# How can I use a custom text font in LilyPond?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

I'm trying to use the "Hiragino Mincho ProN" font for Japanese text on the title, but I don't know how to use fonts, not even the other default ones (Sans and Typewriter).

I don't have any knowledge of programming, so if I have to make use of Scheme, I'm quite lost x'D

I've tried to understand the manual, but I don't really get it. And on top of that, English is not my mother language, so that might be another issue.

Can anyone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have this font installed, you should just be able to insert a `\paper` block clarifying your fonts at the start of your file (after your version statement):

```
\paper {
  fonts = #
  (make-pango-font-tree
   "Hiragino Mincho ProN" % use this for the main (Roman) font
   "etc" % your sans font
   "etc" % your monospace font
   (/ (* staff-height pt) 2.5))
}
```

See also the discussion in [the Lilypond documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/fonts#entire-document-fonts) about changing fonts (it has slightly different code that should do the same job).